# How can I add an image with HTML.fromHtml

Tags: android

I am using the method HTML.fromHtml in android to show some about text in my app. Is it possible to add an image into my about text and if so how?

Here is my activity where the aboutText will be started

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_information);

    int versionNumber = 0;
    String versionName = "";

    try{
        PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo( getPackageName(), 0 );
        versionNumber = pInfo.versionCode;
        versionName = pInfo.versionName;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e){
        Log.e( TAG, "error while extracting version name and version number" + e.getMessage() );
    }

    TextView about = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.about_text_view );
    Spanned aboutText = Html.fromHtml( "<h1> PDiX Attach, Version " + versionName + "</h1>"
                                         + getString( R.string.about_text ));

    about.setText( aboutText );


}
```

And the resours R.id.about_text looks like this:

```
        <b>Requirements:</b>
        <br/>The application supports Android Devices with Version 2.2 or higher.
        <br/>HERE I WANT TO ADD AN IMAGE<br/>

        </body>


        ]]>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use WebView if you want add an image.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a guess here and assume that by now you know that you should use a WebView to show HTML with a local image. I'm guessing that what you need to know is how to slip the image into the HTML string. I'm a rookie here so I don't know if my solution is the best, but for what it's worth, here's what I did. In short, I converted a Bitmap image into a Base64 string.

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import android.util.Base64;

...

    Bitmap image = [insert appropriate code here];
    String encodedImage = null;
    if ( image != null ) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); // PNG preserves transparancy 
        byte[] byteArrayImage = baos.toByteArray();
        encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
        String imageHTML = "<img src='data:image/jpg;base64," + 
            encodedImage + "'/>";
    }
```

I hope this helps. (And as a postscript, my thanks to all who have responded to queries like this on forums all over the Net. Your patience and kindness has help me learn so much.)